# C++ Sockets work with bits instead of bytes

Tags: c++, sockets, memory, compression

I need to use as little memory as possible because I have to send long arrays of chars through the internet multiple times a second. While learning zlib, a question came to my mind. 
My chars can only be 1 or 0. They can be represented with one single bit. Isn't it inefficent to send the whole byte? Just by sending only one bit per value, i'd get 8 times compression. Can I send individual bits instead of bytes?

Comment: No, but you can turn each 0|1 character into a bit and send 8 of them in a single byte.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send single bit because in the underlying level [IP protocol sends size of packet in bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Total_Length).

However, you can manually pack your bits in single byte and send it. That will be more efficient.

Comment: I'll add that IP (plus presumably either a UDP or TCP layer) will add substantial networking/processing overhead to sending a single byte/octet at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Well you cant, as far as C/C++ is concerned in socket programming context. It is not possible to have a datatype less than one byte.

Answer (score -2):

Your question just shows that you do not understand what bit and byte is. Byte is a group of 8 bits, nothing less, nothing more. You can interpret it as unsigned number 0-255, or signed number -128 - +127, as ASCII letter or as **8 separate bits**. Sockets send bytes, so if you want to send bits, you will have to group them in 8 boundary, that's it. How you pack that data it is completely up to you, network and socket library does not care.

Comment: The byte is not exactly 8 bits. It may be smaller, it may be bigger. `8` is just a too common size for them. But, there are processors with smaller bytes. In case you don't believe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: @AlexeyShmalko there is a difference how byte defined for different CPU and how it is defined to C machine and network. I believe latter is exactly 8 bits.

Comment: C doesn't define byte.

Comment: @AlexeyShmalko I don't want to start a debate here, anyway socket library expects 8bits data de-facto. I would like to see how it would be implemented on non 8bit byte CPU.

Comment: 1) Truncate each byte to 8 bits or 2) treat char array as a sequence of bits. That doesn't really matter. However, you're right, IEEE defines byte to be exactly octet.